# Docker compose run bash with special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, character-encoding, docker-compose, containers

I've been looking through the internet but I haven't found anything about this.

I'm trying to use special characters (e.g.: **ç**, **ã**, **í**, etc) inside a ruby string in my web app container rail's console, but when I type any of those the letter just don't appear.

I thought it could be something with my terminal's encoding set, but when I exit from the container's console, I can type any special character.

To verify that, try running (supposing you have a `web` container image)

`sh
$ docker-compose run web bash
root@<container_id>:/var/www/cegonha$ <try to put any special character or letter with accent here>`

Can anyone help me with this? I really need to put a ruby script that contains a string with special characters.

Comment: check container's console encoding. Also, try your script despite the fact that console does not work as expected. please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set any $TERM value?
in my container

`user@localhost-:~$ docker exec -e TERM=xterm -it localcontainer bash -c "echo ç, ã, í"
ç, ã, í
user@localhost-:~$`